# Can't add to global variable

Tags: c++

So first of all, I'm new and this is probably a really dumb mistake I'm making here but still, I don't see where the problem is. So what I am trying to achieve here, is basically a drink counter, essentially you tell the program your name and it adds 1 drink to you're variable.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int Kevin = 0;
int Stephie = 0;
int Erich = 0;
int TomLaurin = 0;
int Christian = 0;
int Torsten = 0;
int Jannis = 0;
int Frederic = 0;
int Phillip = 0;
int Sina = 0;
int Mario = 0;
int Walter = 0;

int main()
{
    for (; ; ) {

        int Person;

        std::cout << "Bitte geben sie ihre Nummer ein: \n";
        std::cout << "Kevin = 1 \n";
        std::cout << "Stephie = 2 \n";
        std::cout << "Erich = 3 \n";
        std::cout << "Tom-Laurin = 4 \n";
        std::cout << "Christian = 5 \n";
        std::cout << "Torsten = 6 \n";
        std::cout << "jannis = 7 \n";
        std::cout << "Frederic = 8 \n";
        std::cout << "Phillip = 9 \n";
        std::cout << "Sina = 10 \n";
        std::cout << "Mario = 11 \n";
        std::cout << "Walter = 12 \n";
        scanf_s("%d", &Person);

        switch (Person)
        {
        case 1:
            (Kevin + 1);
            std::cout << "Das ist dein " << Kevin << ". Getraenk \n";
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
        }

    }
}
```

After my understanding, it should after I entered the number 1 print: "Das ist dein 1. Getraenk", but what it does, is that it prints: "Das ist dein 0. Getraenk"

Comment: There is no reason for any of those variables to be global.

Comment: @NeilButterworth It actually does not make any difference

Comment: @ P__J__ Precisely, so why make them global? Or mention the fact that they are global in the question title?

Comment: @NeilButterworth OP is a very novice programmer. He still have a right to ask this kind of questions.

Answer (score 1):

`(Kevin + 1);` -> `Kevin++;` or `++Kevin` or `Kevin += 1;` or `Kevin = Kevin + 1;`

`(Kevin + 1);` does not have any effect.

Comment: It took me three tries to understand what you wrote. I'd recommend you use a sentence instead of '->'.

Comment: @Aganju it is so simple :)